# Change bookmarks from left sidebar to top bar in Safari 7.0.6

Tags: bookmarks, safari, system-preferences

A new safari update places the bookmarks on in a quarter screen left navigation.  Does anyone know a way to move it back to the top.  (I did not see anything in preference and it appeared that under the bookmarks tab it just allows an on off options.)

Answer (score 2):

A way of keeping you favourites in the top is by enabling `View → Show Favourites Bar` or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Then you could move all your bookmarks to your favourites bar and never show the sidebar again.

Comment: I like big players like apple: 8 years old and your tooltip still working.